# Simple SQL query for all results

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Travel]
(
    [TE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TRAVEL_TYPE] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [TRAVEL_MODE] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [TRAVEL_CLASS] [nchar](10) NULL)

SET PRIMARY KEY TO TE_ID

INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Return', 'Airlines', 'Economy')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Single', 'Airlines', 'Business')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Return', 'Airlines', 'Business')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Single', 'Railway', 'Second')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Return', 'Railway', 'First')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Return', 'Airlines', 'Business')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Travel] VALUES  ('Return', 'Airlines', 'Economy')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Journey]
(
    [JOURNET_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [JOURNEY_FROM] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [JOURNEY_TO] [varchar](30) NULL)

SET PRIMARY KEY TO [JOURNET_ID]

INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (1,'Mumbai','PUNE')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (1,'PUNE','Mumbai')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (2,'BANGALORE','GOA')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (3,'CHENNAI','PANAJI')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (3,'PANAJI','CHENNAI')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (4,'DELHI','KOLKATA')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (5,'BHOPAL','SHIMALA')
INSERT INTO [TAMSMVC].[dbo].[tbl_Journey] VALUES (5,'SHIMALA','BHOPAL')
```

and the result should be:

```
Journey_ID  TE_ID   Journey_From    Journey_To  TRAVEL_TYPE [TRAVEL_MODE    TRAVEL_CLASS    CountofTEID
1           1       Mumbai          PUNE        Return      Airlines         Economy        2
3           2       BANGALORE       GOA         Single      Airlines         Business       1
4           3       CHENNAI         PANAJI      Return      Airlines         Business       2
6           4       DELHI           KOLKATA     Single      Railway          Second         1
7           5       BHOPAL          SHIMALA     Return      Railway          First          2
null        6       null            null        Return      Airlines         Economy        0
null        7       null            null        Return      Airlines         Business       0
```

In result I want all rows from `Travel` table, count of all journeys and single record with minimum `journey_id`

Comment: Why have you tagged this as Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql query to get distinct rows in let table in simple two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063445/sql-query-to-get-distinct-rows-in-let-table-in-simple-two-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Something I just tried :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.TE_ID ORDER BY A.TE_ID) AS ROWNO, JOURNET_ID, A.TE_ID, JOURNEY_FROM, JOURNEY_TO, TRAVEL_TYPE, TRAVEL_MODE, TRAVEL_CLASS
INTO #FINALTEMPDATA
FROM #TEMPA A 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT * FROM #TEMPJ J WHERE A.TE_ID = J.TE_ID
) APP

SELECT JOURNET_ID, FA.TE_ID, JOURNEY_FROM, JOURNEY_TO, TRAVEL_TYPE, TRAVEL_MODE, TRAVEL_CLASS, COUNTOFID
FROM #FINALTEMPDATA FA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT FB.TE_ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTOFID FROM #FINALTEMPDATA FB
    GROUP BY FB.TE_ID
) FC ON FA.TE_ID = FC.TE_ID
WHERE FA.ROWNO = 1
```